# How can I write an AJAX function that will load HTML into two different DIVs?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am using Django and AJAX in a project where I am building an activity feed.  The way it works, we show both friend activity and global activity.  This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<div>
  {% include "friend_reviews.html" %}
  <div id="load-friends"></div>
</div>
<div>
  {% include "global_reviews.html" %}
  <div id="load-global"></div>
</div>
<a id="load-more" href="/load/feed/2">
  Load More
</a>
```

**I want to write a jQuery AJAX function that will load additional reviews into #load-friend and #load-global.**  Consequently, I wrote a Django view (which intercepts /load/feed/2) that queries the database and returns:

```
context = {'friend_reviews': friend_reviews, 'global_reviews': global_reviews'}
```

Both friend_reviews and global_reviews are QuerySets of Review objects.  If you plug friend_reviews into the friend_reviews.html partial template, then it will generate the appropriate HTML on the page.

However, I am not that familiar with jQuery and do not know what's the best way to generate the correct HTML.  I have heard about Taconite but there are no examples in Python so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would love to talk more about your activity feed project offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include jquery library in the head of your page.

Then, this will do the job :

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $.get("friend_reviews.html",function(data){     
            $('#load-friends').html(data);
      });
    $.get("global_reviews.html",function(data){     
            $('#load-global').html(data);
      });
});
```

If you want to do it by clicking on the link then you can use following

```
// html
<a id="load-more">Load More</a> 

// Javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#load-more').click(function(){
    $.get("friend_reviews.html",function(data){     
            $('#load-friends').html(data);
      });
    $.get("global_reviews.html",function(data){     
            $('#load-global').html(data);
      });
                                   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then it is even simpler with $(selector).load(url).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#load-more').click(function(){
    $('#load-friends').load("friend_reviews.html");
    $('#load-global').load("global_reviews.html");
    return false;
  });
});
```

It would be more efficient to return everything you need in one (Ajax) request by having /load/feed/2 render JSON containing the required html.

Make the /load/feed/2 view return JSON:

```
context = {'friend_reviews': friend_reviews, 'global_reviews': global_reviews}
response_data = {'friend_reviews': render_to_string('friend_reviews.html', context),
                 'global_reviews': render_to_string('global_reviews.html', context)}

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), mimetype="application/json")
```

Then your javascript could be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#load-more').click(function(){
    $.getJSON($(this).attr('href'), function (data) {
      $('#load-friends').html(data.friend_reviews);
      $('#load-global').html(data.global_reviews);
      });

    return false;
  });
});
```

You need to take care that your url (/load/feed/2) now renders JSON so if you need or want it to still render HTML you may want to add a new url for the JSON